# ¿Cómo actualizar marcadores en tiempo real con Google Maps API Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, google-maps

estoy desarrollando una aplicacion web que muestra marcadores consultados de una base de datos remota. Lo que sucede es que si agrego un nuevo registro a la base de datos, el nuevo marcador no aparece hasta que limpio la caché del navegador, sólo en ese caso los nuevos registros se pueden ver reflejados correctamente.

El funcionamiento es el siguiente, primero hago un click sobre el mapa para situar un nuevo marcador, una vez situado donde lo necesito le hago click y esto abre un modal que extrae la lat y lng del marcador que acabo de situar, presiono guardar en el modal y esto envía los datos a un php que almacena los datos en la bd.
Luego de esto necesito que se refresquen los marcadores y aparezca el nuevo marcador recién guardado en la bd (cosa que no sucede), el dato se guarda correctamente pero no es posible visualizar su marcador respectivo en el mapa.

Aquí les dejo mi código, espero que alguno pueda ayudarme.

```
 function guardar() {

       var latitude = document.getElementById('lat').value;
       var longitude = document.getElementById('lng').value;
       var texto = document.getElementById('texto').value;

       var data = '&latitude='+latitude+'&longitude='+longitude+'&texto='+texto;
       $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'guardar_marcador.php',
        data: data,
        beforeSend: function(data) {

           initMap();
           $('#MyModal').modal('hide');
        },
        success: function(data) {
          //eliminarCookies();

          location.reload(true);

        }
      });
     }
    function initMap(){
         ........muchas otras cosas.....

              //consumir web services con marcadores de alertas

              $.getJSON('eventos.php', function(responsedata) {

                   $.each( responsedata.puntos, function(i, value) {
                        if(value.lat!="" && value.lng!="" )
                        {

                              console.log("marcador "+i);

                              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                 position: {lat: parseFloat(value.lat), lng: parseFloat(value.lng)},
                                 animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                                 title: value.DisplayName+','+ value.ChaserLocation,
                                 icon:  icono_evento,
                                 map: map
                               });

                               marker.setMap(map);

                               marker.addListener('click', function() {

                                 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                                   content: '<div id="content">'+
                                              '<div id="siteNotice">'+
                                              '</div>'+
                                              '<h5 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">'+value.texto+'</h5>'+
                                              '<div id="bodyContent">'+
                                              '<b> '+value.fecha+'</b><br>' +
                                              '</div>'+
                                            '</div>'
                                 });
                                 infowindow.open(map, marker);
                               });

                       }
                    });
                 });


       //funcion para situar y guardar un nuevo marcador en la bd
                 google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
                    if(cont<1){
                      placeMarker(event.latLng);
                      // var controlDiv = document.getElementById('floating-panel');
                      // map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER].push(controlDiv);
                      cont=1;
                    }else{
                      console.log('Sólo puedes crear un marcador a la vez!');
                      initMap();

                    }

                  });

                  //funcion para agregar un marcador con un click
                  function placeMarker(location) {

                      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                          position: location,
                          draggable:true,
                          map: map,
                          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                          icon: icono_evento
                      });
                      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

                      var latitude = this.position.lat();
                      var longitude = this.position.lng();

                      console.log(latitude+","+longitude);

                      $('#MyModal').modal({
                         show: true
                       })

                       document.getElementById('lat').value = latitude;
                       document.getElementById('lng').value = longitude;

                      });
                  }

     }
```

Comment: Probaste utilizar un socket, esto permite actualizaciones en tiempo real

Comment: @AndrusDiaz Gracias por tu tiempo. No, no lo he probado, buscaré cómo se puede implementar con la API de Google Maps. Aunque creo que si pudiera resetear la vista completa de la página y recargar todos sus componentes quizás bastaría para visualizar los nuevos marcadores ingresados.